# Does Git have trouble merging compiled files?

Tags: git, github, git-merge

So we have a ton of less files that we compile into a 1 line css.  When trying to merge this compiled file it keeps failing. I know we can fix the conflict manually with git gui or gitmergetool.  But i am wondering if this is pretty common for compiled files on one line? anyone else run into this issue?

Thanks
Steve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Merging does not work well if the file is only one line long, because merging works line-by-line.

Merging is designed to work on "source" files, which are the files edited by humans.  Compiled CSS files are not source files.

You have a couple different options:

- After merging the original CSS, resolve the conflicts by recompiling and checking in the recompiled version.  You'll want to set the git attributes on this file to have the `merge` attribute unset, so it won't try to merge.
- Don't check compiled CSS into Git.

Fixing your gitattributes:

```
comiled/*.css -merge
```

Comment: figured this much just wanted to confirm. We can simply merge the non compiled files. no biggie.

thanks Steve

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is yes, but it's not really git's fault.

For a long answer, check out `man diff`:

```
DIFF(1)                          User Commands                          DIFF(1)

NAME
       diff - compare files line by line
```

Basically, every diff tool out there uses newlines to figure out where changes have occurred. It's just the way that Unix / POSIX works, and since all diff tools are designed to work like `diff`, they'll all have this issue.

In general, compiled files shouldn't really be checked into source control, but even if it is, you shouldn't have to worry about these merge conflicts. When you do a `git merge` or `git rebase` and there are conflicts, just deal with the conflict at the source level, recompile that file, and you can assume that it's all good. If it's not all good, then you're compiling things wrong!

Comment: Thanks for the input. We will just merge the un compiled versions.